# Bootstrap dynamic content

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, dynamic, bootstrap

I am building a website powered by twitter's bootstrap. I have created a landing page with menus and text. The next thing I want to do is create a About page, but what is the easiest way to create a new page with the same layout. I don't think copy and pasting the layout would be a great idea.

I have used PHP includes and $_GET variables for this in the past but I wondered if there is a more elegant solution.

I hope this is the place for the question and I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want, here is one method that I used to use.

You have your landing page complete, so I assume you have a header with the navigation menus and other information on that page, you have some content in the middle of the page, and you have a footer at the bottom.

What you want to do is re-use the header and footer on all pages, and just change the content, so to do this, you could take all the code for your header and put that in a file and call it `header.php`. Next, do the same with your footer, again naming it `footer.php`. Finally, do the same thing with your content, calling it `landing_page.php`.

Now, in your `landing_page.php` is where you join all the files together:

```
<?
include('header.php');
...
output your content here
...
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Now you can reuse your header and footer in other templates (*about.php*, etc) without copying all the header and footer code in each template.

This is a very basic example, and there are lots of other techniques but this should get you pointed in the right direction.

For a much more in-depth approach take a look at The [No Framework Framework](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/38-The-no-framework-PHP-MVC-framework.html).

Comment: is this the same as the "I have used PHP includes" part of the question ?

Comment: No it is not, I used to use $_GET[''] variables for the page numbers and then query a database for the correct page. For the basic static pages I went with phrac's solution. For the dynamic and interactive part of the website's I used my own version of a GET and DB query system. http://pastie.org/6347828

Answer (score 0):

From a code maintenance point of view, PHP includes are the cleanest way I've come across; another option that I've tried in the past are Dreamweaver template files (think include files that are internal inside of Dreamweaver) but when you publish the file its pure HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: I also used Dreamweaver template files in the past but the project I'm working on can't be Dreamweaver dependent. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method would to be use a CMS (Content Management System) there are many Bootstrap frameworks that are compiled and ready to use for many different content management systems. This makes adding content and various pages a breeze. It shouldn't be to hard to take what you have done already and input that into a pre-built framework for a CMS.

- [Bootstrap for WordPress](http://320press.com/wpbs/)
- [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org) (Default template uses a Bootstrap)
- [Bootstrap for Drupal](http://drupal.org/project/twitter_bootstrap)

If you still rather use STATIC design then you can use Dreamweaver and save your design blank as a template which makes making new pages faster but its still not as easy as using a CMS. Take a look at [saving time in Dreamweaver](http://layersmagazine.com/save-time-with-templates-in-dreamweaver.html).